# Statistical methods for Sequence learning

Tags: statistics, prediction, sequence

I am bit more traditional and I am looking for a statistical method that can help me also do inference or predictions.

I have some table that contains some transitions, where each row of the table correspond to a specific user. If you are into python this is it:

```
smallData=pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1,2,3,4,5],[4,5,6,7,8],[1,2,3,3,3],[1,2,2,3,3],[1,2,3,5,3]]),columns=range(0,5))
smallData
Out[266]: 
   0  1  2  3  4
0  1  2  3  4  5
1  4  5  6  7  8
2  1  2  3  3  3
3  1  2  2  3  3
4  1  2  3  5  3
```

Now first row means that the following transitions happen
1-2-3-4-5

this kind of transitions can be of course be visualized as a tree or diagram. So far I have not found any method or library in python or R that can calculate the statistics of transitions. For example for the two transitions [1,2] three transition can happen

- Transition 3 by 50%,
- Transition 4 by 25% and
- Transition 5 by 25%.

These were calculated from the table above.

Even harder will be to predict two steps forward.

I have seen the topic of sequence prediction to be discussed a lot in the machine learning community by using LSTM. I still wonder if in the statistics community are methods to handle such problems and if yes if there are in python, R libraries that can be used for such problem.

Answer (score 1):

it sounds like a stochastic process problem. Have you looked into estimating transition matrices for markov chains?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes I have tried it. The problem I see with markov chains is that they model the one-hop transition. I think my problem has also dependencies (memory). I also saw in the literature that people use LSTM to create such generators. Still what I miss is a more statistical-typical approach that can learn and make inference based on memory.

Answer (score 0):

The traditional approach would be Conditional Random Fields (CRFs). CRFs models can be designed with a fixed-size "memory", i.e. taking into account the N previous states (where N is a constant).

There are some tools available like [CRF++](https://taku910.github.io/crfpp/) or [Wapiti](https://wapiti.limsi.fr/), but I don't know about python or R libraries.